# Java, асинхронная отправка множества get-запросов

Tags: java, многопоточность

Здравствуйте! 
Возник такой вопрос. 
Как правильно отправлять N (N > 100) get-запроcов в секунду на указанный url?

Для решения этой задачи я испольховал ExecutorService i CountDownLatch.

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(DEFAULT_LATCH_COUNT);
    for (int i = 0; i < requestNumber; i++) {
        executor.submit(RequestFactory.getInstance().createRequester(latch, url));
    }
latch.countDown();
```

Но проблема в том что для каждого нового запроса я создаю новый поток(как отправить асинхронно по другому не знаю) и делаю *await()*, а после того как создано достаточное кол-во потоков - продолжаю их работу одновременно. По скольку время ожидания ответа сервера может быть разным, количество потоков растет и в конце концов может привести к окончанию памяти.

Подскажите есть ли варианты сделать это другим способом ?

Comment: Установить лимит потоков? Если 100 запросов еще активны, подождать, пока часть завершится и создавать новые.

Comment: Если установить лимит, то в дальнейшем количество запросов буде меньше чем необходимое, потому что свободных потоков не будет достаточно. 
А как вообще на счет такого подхода, один запрос - один подход ? Это норм ?

Comment: Не понял, что Вы имеете ввиду под подходом. Вы сможете добиться 100 запросов в секунду исключительно если Ваш компьютер сможет такое выполнить. В другом случае Вы просто забьете память (поэтому нужно делать максимальное допустимое кол-во запросов).

Comment: Если необходимо отправить 1000 запросов в секунду, то нужно будет создать 1000 потоков. Но разве 1000 потоков это норм ? 
Сори, не селен в многопоточности(

Comment: Сделайте очередь заданий и пул потоков нужного размера. Каждый потоки будет вытягивать задание из очереди, обрабатывать его и вытягивать следующее.

Comment: @АндрійДзигар, я, как Android-разработчик, в серверной многопоточности тоже не силен. Но могу точно сказать: 1 000 потоков — непозволительно.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону NIO (неблокирующего ввода-вывода) и очередей, как написал Сергей. Вот тут, если я не ошибаюсь, на эту тему — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572145/worker-thread-in-java Однако, пересмотрите Ваши требования к программе. Как по мне, они абсурдны... :)

Comment: а зачем вам это нужно? не хотите использовать уже готовое средство?

Comment: Я бы предложил использовать ForkJoinPool. Он нагенерит тасков, а потоков JVM создаст столько, сколько посчитаем нужным. А ответы можно получать асинхронно, через Future

Comment: https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client